# How can I tell the difference between fish and ore?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I like fishing and I like mining. I don't like to do the two things at the same time. So I would like to find a way to quickly differentiate between ore and fish on the minimap. How can I do this without having to hover my mouse pointer over the yellow indicator?

I have used an addon (Gatherer) to help remember where fish and ore are located, but it does not indicate the difference between them until I have mined or fished them. This means that while I explore and discover new fishing pools and ore I have to interact with the mini map by moving my hand rather than by moving my eyes, I find that this breaks the feeling of immersion, so I would prefer to avoid it.

Here is a picture of the minimap

[image]

There are two yellow dots near the center and off to the right there are some greyish dots that the addon has remembred for me. What I hope to achieve is a means of distinguishing between the fishing pools and the ore without having to gather them or to hover my mouse pointer over them. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Also, I suspect support for mods and plugins is off-topic, but I seem to recall from my days playing WoW that Gatherer had a database of known mining/fishing/etc points that could be loaded in, so you don't have to tag them all yourself.  (It may have been distributed as a separate mod. GathererDB or something like that.)

Answer (score 3):

If you only need one type of those indicators you can simply deactivate the others and re-enable them later again once you need them.

Just right-click on the minimap and you will be able to choose what to display. Tick the boxes you want to see (Find Fish, Herbs, Mining Nodes, etc) and untick the one(s) you don't want.

This way you can enable ores when mining or fish when fishing and so on. It's also pretty useful when you have two gathering professions and want to do only one at a time.

[image]

(The option for a gathering profession appears when you have learned that profession.)

Comment: (Find Fish appears if you've gotten the [Weather-Beaten Journal](http://www.wowhead.com/item=34109/weather-beaten-journal) item and used it.  It appears in various crates you can fish up.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a database you can get for the gatherer plugin from the data on wowhead, which, once imported, will have most if not all ore/fishing spots with the appropriate icon, so you can see it at a glance.